Evaluation of Contrastive learning model
I understand in contrastive learning, we have triplet of anchor, positive and negative samples which are defined in advance for supervised contrastive learning, my question is, if I want to evaluate, test my model on a new dataset where I have no labels, how can I define anchor, positive and negative triplet in this situation?

As you say, without labels you can't construct a triplet, so you can't compute the triplet loss. There has been some progress in the area of "weakly supervised learning" but I'm not aware of a weakly supervised contrastive learning method.

What is your recommendation of testing such a model on a new data point without a label?

As far as I know, you'll have to get labels.
